# Implement view photo functionality like in Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, jquery-events

I'm looking to add a twitter feed into my site that shows images posted, but rather than click on an image and it takes you to twitter to see the photo I would like to be able to click on a link called "View Photo" and the image reveals itself underneath, and then reverse the process by clicking "Hide Photo".

So far I have come up with this, however I'm using the deprecated event handler `.live` and was wondering how to go about re-factoring this piece of jQuery to something more efficient as I have read that there are performance issues with `.live`, plus I think that I maybe going about this the wrong way?

```
  $(".twitterImage").hide();
            
   $(".showLink").live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $(this).next(".twitterImage").show();
     $(this).text('Hide Photo').css('display', 'block').removeClass("showLink").addClass("hideLink");
        
   });

    $(".hideLink").live('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
       $(this).next(".twitterImage").hide();
       $(this).text('View Photo').removeClass("hideLink").addClass("showLink");
        
    });
```

Any help appreciated and I'm sure a few of you are looking on in horror reading this, so I do apologise for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use jQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function, and attach the event handler with the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function.  See my example below.

### [*jsFiddle demonstration*](http://jsfiddle.net/jstol/Y9U9Y/)

**HTML**

```
<a class="imageLink" href="#">Show Photo</a>
<img class="twitterImage" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_images/jsfiddle-logo-thumb.png"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.imageLink {
    display: block;
}

.twitterImage {
    display: block;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$(".twitterImage").hide();

$(".imageLink").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text == 'Show Photo' ? 'Hide Photo' : 'Show Photo';
    $(this).text(text);
    $(this).next(".twitterImage").toggle(500);
});
```

Comment: Thats nice :) and good use of ternary operator in there aswell